# Generate a list of IPv6 into an array

Tags: bash, shell-script, array, ipv6

I wrote this script a little while ago :

```
#!/bin/bash

#Default number of IPs
NUM_IPS=48
if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
    NUM_IPS=$1
fi

#Example of IPv6 supplied 2001:41d0:0303:6e1b::/64

read -p "Starting IPv6 : " IPv6
IPv6_c=$(echo $IPv6 | sed -e 's/\/64//g' | sed -e 's/:*$//g')
IPv6_e=$(sed -e 's#.*:\(\)#\1#' <<< "$IPv6_c")
IPv6_s=$(echo $IPv6_c | sed -e "s/$IPv6_e//g")
IPv6_t1=$(echo $IPv6 | sed -e 's/\/64//g')
IPv6_t2=$(echo $IPv6_t1 | sed -e "s/$IPv6_c//g")
IPv6_t3=$IPv6_t2"/64"

for i in $(seq 0 $((NUM_IPS-1))); do
    printf "$IPv6_s%.4x$IPv6_t3\n" $((i+0x$IPv6_e))
done
```

But this little script simply prints the results. Now I would like to have this generated list of IPv6 into an array to further process them. How may I do this ?

Thanks in advance

PS. If you have a better way of formatting the IPv6 feel free to share ;)

EDIT :

Example of result of ipv6 variables:

```
Starting IPv6 : 2001:41d0:0303:6e1b::/64

IPv6_c......: 2001:41d0:0303:6e1b
IPv6_e......: 6e1b
IPv6_s......: 2001:41d0:0303:
IPv6_t1.....: 2001:41d0:0303:6e1b::
IPv6_t2.....: ::
IPv6_t3.....: ::/64
```

Comment: To add an element to an array, use `arr+=(element)`

Comment: Do you happen to know a better way of generating the ipv6 from this input example ? (I add the example variables in my post)

Comment: @choroba when I echo my array IPv6_ARR+=$(printf "$IPv6_s%.4x$IPv6_t3\n" $((i+0x$IPv6_e))) like this echo $IPv6_ARR[0], it echos the entire generated list without even separating the result. Any leads on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the result that works for me :

```
#!/bin/bash

Generate_IPv6(){
    #Variables
    if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
        NUM_IPS=$1
    else
        NUM_IPS=48
    fi
    if [ "$2" != "" ]; then
        IPv6=$2
    else
        read -p "Starting IPv6 : " IPv6
    fi
    IPv6_c=$(echo $IPv6 | sed -e 's/\/64//g' | sed -e 's/:*$//g')
    IPv6_e=$(sed -e 's#.*:\(\)#\1#' <<< "$IPv6_c")
    IPv6_s=$(echo $IPv6_c | sed -e "s/$IPv6_e//g")
    IPv6_t1=$(echo $IPv6 | sed -e 's/\/64//g')
    IPv6_t2=$(echo $IPv6_t1 | sed -e "s/$IPv6_c//g")
    IPv6_t3=$IPv6_t2"/64"
    for i in $(seq 0 $((NUM_IPS-1))); do
        IPv6_RR+="$(printf "$IPv6_s%.4x$IPv6_t3\n" $((i+0x$IPv6_e))) "
    done
    IFS=' ' read -r -a IPv6_ARR <<< "$IPv6_RR[0]"
}
Generate_IPv6 "$1" "$2"
```

So basically `IPv6_RR+="$(printf "$IPv6_s%.4x$IPv6_t3\n" $((i+0x$IPv6_e))) "` creates the list separated by space, then `IFS=' ' read -r -a IPv6_ARR <<< "$IPv6_RR[0]"` creates the array